# Error when packaging Electron app to macOS

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, electron-packager

I'm trying to package my Electron app for macOS, however when I try to package it using Windows I get this error: 
`The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined`

I'm using Electron 4.2.6 and electron-packager

The source is available at: https://github.com/cozy-penguin/client/
I'm new to working with Electron so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think its convention in StackOverflow to copy / paste **only the relevant parts** of your code here rather than linking to an external git repo. This makes it easier for others who want to help you get to the debugging step faster.

Comment: @onlyphantom I'm trying to package, not fix bugs. I don't know where it's gone wrong.